# Toast notification not working in Xamarin UWP Windows app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I have UWP Windows application, developed under the Xamarin.forms. I have implemented the Toast notifications but I am facing the issue with this. In some Windows 10 systems, it is working and showing the toast notification properly, but in some of the Windows 10 systems (even having the same Windows 10 OS update) it is not working.

Below first code snippets that I have implemented in the Native UWP.

```
string msg = "Toast Notification Header";
                string subMsg = "Toast Notification Title";

                var toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastText02);

                var toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
                toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(msg));
                toastTextElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(subMsg));

                //To play the custom sound
                var toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
                var audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");
                audio.SetAttribute("src", "ms-appx:///Assets/incoming_message.wav");
                audio.SetAttribute("loop", "false");
                toastNode.AppendChild(audio);

                var toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
                ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

Below second code snippets that I have implemented in the Native UWP.

```
// "With Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications"


                // Construct the toast content
                ToastContent toastContent = new ToastContent()
                {
                    Visual = new ToastVisual()
                    {
                        BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
                        {
                            Children =
                    {
                        new AdaptiveText()
                        {
                            Text = "Toast Notification Header"
                        },

                        new AdaptiveText()
                        {
                            Text = "Toast Notification Content"
                        }
                    }
                        }
                    }
                };

                bool supportsCustomAudio = true;

                // If we're running on Desktop before Version 1511, do NOT include custom audio
                // since it was not supported until Version 1511, and would result in a silent toast.
                if (AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily.Equals("Windows.Desktop")
                    && !ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract", 2))
                {
                    supportsCustomAudio = false;
                }

                if (supportsCustomAudio)
                {
                    toastContent.Audio = new ToastAudio()
                    {
                        Src = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/incoming_message.wav")                          
                    };
                }

                // And create the toast notification
                ToastNotification notification = new ToastNotification(toastContent.GetXml());
                // And then send the toast
                ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(notification);
```

Above code snips showing the Toast notification in some Windows 10 system and not working in some other Windows 10 system.
Kindly guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Hi, What systems do you mean that some systems do not support? In devices that do not pop up notifications normally, you can check whether you have enabled notification push permissions for the app in `Settings`-> `System`-> `Notifications and Action`

Comment: The system means the Windows 10 system, some Windows 10 system is showing the notification and some are not showing, even systems having the same Windows update version. I have already checked the notification permissions and it is enabled across all the systems.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear, there are multiple release versions of Windows 10, do you test the same system? If some of the same version can push notifications, and some can't, then this should have nothing to do with the code, but the configuration of the computer

Comment: I have checked with multiple systems having the latest and same 1909 version of Windows 10. In one system it is working and in another system, the same is not working.

Comment: Sorry I cannot reproduce this problem. Maybe we can find the cause of the problem through testing:  
1. Create notifications using `Xamarin.Forms` and `Native UWP`, respectively, and test them on multiple systems. This is to see if the problem is related to the development framework.
2. Create a simple notification (contains only text) for testing, this is to confirm whether the problem is related to the creation of the notification.
3. If neither of the above can provide clear information, then it may be the cause of the system (try to enable the developer mode in the system)

Comment: I have the same issue, the toast notifications in release mode, after publish it, doesn't work. Otherwise when you are in debugging mode

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to add toast notification in UWP Project.

Step 1:- Create a new UWP project.

Step 2:- Go to the code-behind and add the namespace.

> using Windows.UI.Notifications;
>   using
>   NotificationsExtensions.Toasts;

Step 3:- I created a Toast Generic Template like the following code:

```
public static Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument CreateToast()    
{    
   var xDoc = new XDocument(    
      new XElement("toast",    
      new XElement("visual",    
      new XElement("binding", new XAttribute("template", "ToastGeneric"),    
      new XElement("text", "C# Corner"),    
      new XElement("text", "Do you got MVP award?")    
   )    
   ),// actions    
   new XElement("actions",    
   new XElement("action", new XAttribute("activationType", "background"),    
   new XAttribute("content", "Yes"), new XAttribute("arguments", "yes")),    
   new XElement("action", new XAttribute("activationType", "background"),    
   new XAttribute("content", "No"), new XAttribute("arguments", "no"))    
   )    
   )    
   );    

   var xmlDoc = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();    
   xmlDoc.LoadXml(xDoc.ToString());    
   return xmlDoc;    
}
```

Step 4:- Create a toast notification object using XML document.

```
var xmdock = CreateToast();    
var toast = new ToastNotification(xmdock);    
Next show the toast using ToastNotificationManager class.    
var notifi = Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();    
notifi.Show(toast);
```

Step 5:- C# code-behind:

```
private void showToastBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
{    
    var xmdock = CreateToast();    
    var toast = new ToastNotification(xmdock);    
    var notifi = Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();    
    notifi.Show(toast);    
}
```

I hope the above code will be useful for you.

Thank you